# Move object while holding button in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode, touchesbegan

I have a little Space Invaders game and I added two buttons `leftButton` and `rightButton` and I want the `ship` to move as long as one of the buttons is touched AND HELD in the proper direction.

I made it move in the right direction but I have to tap the button repeatedly, but I want `ship` to move WHILE the player is holding the button.

For simplicity I only posted code for the left button as I believe the way to code the other button is identical:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
   var leftButton = SKSpriteNode()
   var ship = SKSpriteNode()

   override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
       leftButton = self.childNode(withName: "left") as! SKSpriteNode
       ship = self.childNode(withName: "player") as! SKSpriteNode
   }

   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
       for touch: AnyObject in touches {
           let pointTouched = touch.location(in: self)

           if leftButton.contains(pointTouched) {
               player.position.x -= 30
           }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: For constant moving use update: method and change directly position property (without using actions).

Comment: Or if you use physics, apply force to node's physics body in the mentioned method.

Comment: if you do not want to clutter your update method, then you can use an action on the touchdown event, and remove the action with the touch up event.  Just make sure you use moveTo, and use the distance of where you are at to the edge to determine the time.  (If it takes 5 seconds to go across the entire screen, then it should take you 2.5 seconds)

Comment: sorry, I do not understand how to implement an updated method on that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an Action for that. There are other ways to implement this, but this will work for you.

First add a `func moveBy`that takes the direction you want your ship to go and a `key: String`. You will use these in your `touchesBegan` later.

```
func moveShip (moveBy: CGFloat, forTheKey: String) {
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: moveBy, y: 0, duration: 1)
    let repeatForEver = SKAction.repeatForever(moveAction)
    let seq = SKAction.sequence([moveAction, repeatForEver])

    //run the action on your ship
    player.run(seq, withKey: forTheKey)
}
```

TouchesBegan:

```
        if leftButton.contains(pointTouched) {
            moveShip(moveBy: -30, forTheKey: "left")
        }

        if rightButton.contains(pointTouched) {
            moveShip(moveBy: 30, forTheKey: "right")
        }
```

EDIT:

touchesEnded:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    player.removeAction(forKey: "left")
    player.removeAction(forKey: "right")
}
```

Comment: this actually worked thank you so much! I just needed to add a removeAction in touchesEnded. maybe you can edit this to your answer, so everybody knows!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SKAction for that: `

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
  var leftButton = SKSpriteNode()
  var ship = SKSpriteNode()
       let Left = SKAction.repeatForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.5),
            SKAction.run({
              SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: -30, dy: 0), duration:0.5)
            }  )]))
 //This SKAction will repeat it self forever, until the action is removed. It's build from a sequence of to other actions, move and wait.
  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
      leftButton = self.childNode(withName: "left") as! SKSpriteNode
     ship = self.childNode(withName: "player") as! SKSpriteNode
   }

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event:UIEvent?) {
      for touch: AnyObject in touches {
          let pointTouched = touch.location(in: self)

          if leftButton.contains(pointTouched) {
         self.run(Left, withKey: "left")
    //Keys will help you remove actions, as well as to remove certain actions, sorting them by group
          }
    }
 }
     override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)   {
    self.removeAction(forKey: "left")

}
     }
```

UPDATE
The way you code your button is really weird I do it this way and it always works: `

```
 if let touch = touches.first{
          let pos = touch.location(in: self)
          let node = self.atPoint(pos)
          if node == button {

              if let view = view {

                   //your code

            }

         }}
```

`

Comment: As this makes absolute sense to me, and I did exactly that, when I press the leftButton, it still does not move the ship. I just dont see how the button is connected to the ship with the action. thank you anyways, it really difficult finding any answers to swift that are up to date!